# Transfer options from SEZ Airport to Mahé Ferry Terminal

Tags: airport-transfer, ferries, seychelles, sez

My flight is scheduled to arrive in Mahé at 14:30 and the ferry I booked leaves at 16:30. They offer a bus transfer at 15:00 but only for planes arriving before 14:00. I will not have a rental car since not staying on the island.

**What options are left to get on time from the airport to the ferry terminal?** And how much approximately would it cost?

Just to be specific, in case there is more than one terminal, the only I am going to is:

> Inter Island Quay, Victoria

Comment: @pnuts - Will try. I'll have 7 more countries to add soon :)

Comment: @pnuts - Probably it's due to the clearing customs and baggage collection time. The 2 PM limit is found mentioned in several places including [this one](https://www.seychellesbookings.com/cat-cocos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are private buses that go from the airport to the ferry terminal, the last departure is 3:30 PM since that is the latest one can make it to the 4:30 PM boat. They charge 10 Euros per person. You have to ask at the *Creol* counter just outside of the arrivals door since these buses are unmarked, have no numbers and no logo (other than the manufacturer of the bus).

Public busses exist to but cannot be used if you have luggage. Apparently, anything larger than a backpack. Since I had a suitcase, I did not inquire on the price.

Answer (score 2):

One option is taxi: [Airport - Victoria : € 20 : transfer time 15 mins](http://www.seychelles-last-minute.com/pt_68.html).

Comment: Unfortunately the URL is dead